# Join Table 1 with Table 2 and the Table 2 has two foreign key column in each raw

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two Tables as given below -

[image]

[image]

I would like to write a SQL query (SQL server Database) to get the data in Result table format.
Please help me to write the SQL query which is follows the best practice rule.
[image]

Comment: Is it the best practice to do that ?

Comment: "best practice" is logically irrelevant here. it is the natural and usual choice for this schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join table2 simply twice

```
SELECT  Pincode,t2.Lcationname,t3.Lcationname
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.SourceLocation_id = t2.LocationId
INNER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t1.DestLocation_id = t3.LocationId
```